# How do I "loop" this else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new to Python and I am having trouble with this 'quiz' I am creating.

```
answer_1_choices = {
    'A' : 'A: A list is a datatype that stores a sequence of items with individual indexes that are mutable.',
    'B' : 'B: A list is a datatype that stores a sequence of items with individual indexes that are immutable.',
    'C' : 'C: A list is a datatype that stores a sequence of items assigned to individual keys that are immutable.'
    }
Number_One = '1. What is a list?'

def answer():
    x = input()
    if x == 'A' or x == 'a':
        print('Correct!')
    else:
        print('That is an incorrect response.  Please try again.' + '\n' + '\n' + Number_One + '\n')
        print(answer_1_choices['A'] + '\n' + '\n' + answer_1_choices['B'] + '\n' + '\n' +  answer_1_choices['C'])
        print('\n' + 'Is the answer A, B, or C?  Type the letter of your choice.')

def question_one():
    print(Number_One + '\n')
    print(answer_1_choices['A'] + '\n' + '\n' + answer_1_choices['B'] + '\n' + '\n' +  answer_1_choices['C'])
    print('\n' + 'Is the answer A, B, or C?  Type the letter of your choice.')


question_one()
answer()
```

I want the else statement to run infinitely every time that the input is something other than 'A' or 'a'.  I know I have to use some kind of loop or something, but I just can't seem to figure it out.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe a `while True:` loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're thinking of there is a `while` loop. Instead of checking for `x = 'A' or x = 'a'`, you might try testing for whether `x` isn't `'A'` or `'a'`.

Try this:

```
while (x != 'A' and x != 'a'):
    print('That is an incorrect response.  Please try again.' + '\n' + '\n' + Number_One + '\n')
    print(answer_1_choices['A'] + '\n' + '\n' + answer_1_choices['B'] + '\n' + '\n' +  answer_1_choices['C'])
    x = input('\n' + 'Is the answer A, B, or C?  Type the letter of your choice.')
print('Correct!')
```

This way, it will only print "Correct!" once the breaking condition has been satisfied.

Comment: You should change `X` inside the loop.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks, I also changed the last print statement to the prompt for input.

Comment: Thank you!! I rearranged a few things and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Add as the last line of the else case a recursive call:

```
 answer()
```

Full code:

```
def answer():
    x = input()
    if x == 'A' or x == 'a':
        print('Correct!')
    else:
        print('That is an incorrect response.  Please try again.' + '\n' + '\n' + Number_One + '\n')
        print(answer_1_choices['A'] + '\n' + '\n' + answer_1_choices['B'] + '\n' + '\n' +  answer_1_choices['C'])
        print('\n' + 'Is the answer A, B, or C?  Type the letter of your choice.')
        answer()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161132/discussion-on-answer-by-tal-how-do-i-loop-this-else-statement).